# Restricted C Struct Randomizer

Tags: c, random, struct, layout

I am attempting to randomize members of a C struct with a few difficulties:

1. The randomized struct may not be larger than the original one
2. Each member has an alignment which has to be respected
3. Members are of different sizes obviously
4. Some members are fixed in place
5. Members may not overlap with respect to their sizes
6. Each member has a range in which it has to end up [min offset, max offset]

I freestyled a randomizer that respects properties 1 to 5. Also taking into account property 6 greatly complicates things. Is there an algorithm that does this kind of thing or could be abused to do it?

For context:

I have this struct representing the properties of a member of a C struct:

```
struct Member {
    uint32_t size;
    uint32_t offset;
    uint32_t alignment;
    uint32_t maxadd; // Max increase of offset
    uint32_t maxsub; // Max decrease of offset
};
```

My randomizer gets a list of objects of this struct, one object per member. It is supposed to find new, randomized offsets for each member, while not having any members overlap in the end and not translating a member by more than maxadd/maxsub.

I am not trying to randomize the strings in a struct definition. I am trying to randomize the memory layout itself. Because it is supposed to work on fully compiled binaries, the resulting layout may not consume more memory than the original struct (e.g. by translating a member by a million bytes). My randomizer also knows the size of the original struct.

Comment: I think you're saying that you want to generate randomized structure *types*?  Some kind of code generation?  Because little of what you say makes any sense for the contents of a structure type given to you.

Comment: I am trying to perform structure layout randomization on fully compiled binaries. I know what the structure layout was before and want to randomize the order of the members. Then I replace displacements in all instructions accessing a member of the struct. Problem is, that e.g. a displacement of 64 bytes cannot be replaced with a 128 byte displacement, because that would increase the length of the instruction. Thus I get a restriction for the member at a 64 byte offset to be pushed backwards at most 63 more bytes (simplified).

Comment: Also, I am trying to use it on the task_struct of the Linux kernel, which has several hundred members and is multiple kB in size. It all needs to run fairly quickly, so just trying until all restrictions were respected once by chance is not an option.

Comment: You're going to need to show code for context here, as what you're describing is not a "structure" at least as far as a `struct` is concerned.

Comment: The problem you describe reminds me of the 0/1 Knapsack problem, but yours is considerably more constrained.

Comment: Have to wonder whether there are compiler optimizations that make this impossible. For example, two `uint8_t` members next to each other (`a` and `b`), with two lines of code that copy the values to a new structure, i.e. `dst->a = src->a;` followed by `dst->b = src->b`. In theory, an optimizer could implement those two lines of code with a single 16-bit move instruction. But that 16-bit move won't work after you rearrange the structure.

Comment: So far, I have only encountered this on gcc O3. It actually also does this with multiple pointers etc. using SIMD registers. I am not entirely sure though, which exact optimization pass does this. Would be interesting to know.

Comment: Just checked. Apparently it is caused by -ftree-slp-vectorize. Apparently this was enabled with O2 in earlier versions of gcc but nowadays only comes with O3. Adding -fno-tree-slp-vectorize to the build command effectively solves the issue.

Comment: Ok, as long as you're aware that the optimizer can make a mess of things, my suggestion is that you limit yourself to rearranging members of the same type. So for example, only swap an `int` with another `int`, or with a `double` with another `double`. Don't be tempted to swap 2 `int`s with a `double`. That's not guaranteed to work because **(A)** `2*sizeof(int)` might not equal `sizeof(double)`, **(B)** the ints might not be properly aligned for a `double`,  and **(C)** technically (but unlikely) there could be padding between the ints.